# Problem on Teams personnel tab iOs with PHPSESSID

Tags: php, ios, microsoft-teams

When I open my personnalTab, I connect to my application but after the modal close I am not redirected on my application and I have an error showing a 403 forbidden access.

When I log the requests on the server side I can see that the PHPSESSID is different from my home application page and my login modal but only on iOs, on Android there no such problem.

My first idea about the problem was that the webView used in teams mobile iOs does not handle correctly SameSite=None; as when I tested adding SameSite=None;Secure; nothing changed, then I tried Lax and Strict but still nothing changed on iOs but it stopped working on Android showing me the same error.

After this I thought that I was about redirection as I use window.location.replace and I found that it could create a bug as it does not add an entry in the browser history so I changed to window.location.assign but once again it changed nothing

It looks like the PHPSESSID is not communicating correctly between my login app and the rest of my application and I find nothing about it online, if someone have some ideas or experienced the same problem I would be glad to test what you did.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what your application does when you open it. Are you opening Task module and that is getting closed? i see that you mentioned model is getting closed.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, So let me explain. When i open my application it open on the homepage of my teams-personnal application. On this screen i can click on a button that will open my teams-authentication app which is an app just used for the login, once i'm logged the teams-authentication close itself and get me back to my homepage of teams-personnal which will then redirect me on the logged page of teams-personnal once it has the answer from the server with the correct PHPSESSID, notice that all of these apps share the same backend

Comment: Could you please share your manifest? That will help to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, thanks for your help, it looks like it was an update of teams-js library that caused the bug, once i upgraded from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0 there was no more problems.